# FF4 nsIDOMWindowInternal.length error

Tags: firefox, firefox4

I'm using Firefox 4.0.1, jquery-latest.js v1.6.1, 
when I try to open a window I get the following error:

> Component returned failure code:
>   0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)
>   [nsIDOMWindowInternal.length].

while on console of Firebug there is no error.
This happens only using Firefox  and not I.E.

Comment: This doesn't look like an error that can be caused by a website (with jQuery or not) - rather one of the extensions installed.